# How to use RESTEasy Client-Proxy with MultipartFile

Tags: java, spring-boot, file-upload, multipartform-data, resteasy

I tried for several days to use the RESTEasy Client-Proxy with Multipart forms.

In the best scenario, I would like to pass a MultipartFile into the Proxy.
E.g.

```
//client:
//Resteasy proxy creation left out for brevity

public Response add(MultipartFile versionFile) {
   proxy.add(versionFile);
}

//server (interface):

@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
FormularDTO add(MultipartFile versionFile);
```

This always ends in an Exception.

```
could not find writer for content-type multipart/form-data type: org.springframework.web.multipart.support
```

As suggested by the Docs, there a two ways to handle Multipart-Files:

a) `MultipartOutput/MultipartInput`:

What should I send via the Proxy? If I send a `MultipartOutput`, I get the same Exception. `MultipartInput` is `Abstract`.

b) Use DTO with `@MultipartForm`
The solution currently used in the project, but requires to map all File-Metadata, create a new DTO, etc.

See Example below:

```
//DTO
public class MultipartFileDataDTO {

    @FormParam("file")
    @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    private InputStream file;

    @FormParam("contentType")
    @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    private String contentType;

     ...
}

//Server-Interface
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
FormularDTO add(@MultipartForm MultipartFileDataDTO versionFile);

//Client-Mapping
MultipartFileDataDTO upload = new MultipartFileDataDTO();
upload.setFile(versionFile.getInputStream());
upload.setContentType(versionFile.getContentType());
...
```

My Question: What is the easiest way to "pass" a MultipartFile via a generated RESTEasy-Client-Proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do would be to create a simple `MultiplartFormDataOutput` object and send it to the proxy.

Here is a simple example:

```
MultipartFormDataOutput output = new MultipartFormDataOutput();
// It is possible to pass a File object or a InputStream in the addFormData
output.addFormData("file", fileObject, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_TYPE, filename);
proxy.add(output)
```